# Does normal HDD enclosure work with Ubuntu?

Tags: external-hdd

Previously I owned a Windows7 laptop which had died few days back. My new laptop runs Ubuntu 16.04.

Now I want to use the HDD of previous laptop as external. 
I can do that right (running windows hdd in ubutu as external) ?

So, before buying any enclosure I wanna know if I need any special kind of enclosure to make it work with Ubuntu or all these random enclosure works fine. Thanks.

Comment: If your enclosure connects via USB, probably. Will you be able to recover anything from the disk? Probably not. Will you be able to reformat the HDD and use it as just another disk? Probably. We can help you. Wikipedia ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_default_file_systems ) says Windows 7 uses the `NTFS` filesystem. Use `NTFS`, rather than "Windows 7" in further questions and searches for best results. The `Search on Ask Ubuntu...` box at the top of the page is one of the best tools.

Comment: I wanna recover files. A user said in the answer it can be done. Guess I'll have use to get the answer. Thanks for mentioning the system NFTS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No special kind of enclosure should be required and Ubuntu should be able to read the NTFS partitions without issue.

I've used a dock like [this one](https://smile.amazon.com/dp/B07415KV63) before without issue.